# How to properly inject extracted css file into head of html file with rollup.js?

Tags: javascript, rollup, rollupjs, rollup-plugin-postcss

I got simple rollup.config.js - everything seems fine to me and should work as I intend it (in the topic title), but only js file getting injected into html. Please help, tried tons of different packages already like rollup-plugin-postcss, rollup-plugin-styles, rollup-plugin-scss, rollup-plugin-sass, and result is always the same - only js injected, and not css.

**rollup.config.js**

```
import path from 'path';
import html from '@rollup/plugin-html';
import url from '@rollup/plugin-url';
import { babel } from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import clear from 'rollup-plugin-clear';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';

import paths from './config/paths';
import { babelExtensions, extensions } from './config/extensions';

// const customResolver = resolve({
//   extensions,
// });

export default {
  input: { login: paths.appLoginIndexJs },
  output: {
    sourcemap: true,
    dir: paths.appBuild,
    format: 'iife',
    assetFileNames: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
    entryFileNames: '[name].[hash].js',
  },
  plugins: [
    commonjs(),
    babel({
      babelHelpers: 'bundled',
      include: ['src/**/*'],
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      extensions: [...babelExtensions, '.html'],
    }),
    html(),
    url({
      include: ['**/*.bmp', '**/*.png', '**/*.jp(e)?g', '**/*.gif', '**/*.webp'],
      filename: '[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
      limit: 7000,
      destDir: path.join(__dirname, 'build', paths.LOGIN_PUBLIC_URL, 'static/images'),
    }),
    url({
      include: ['**/*.otf', '**/*.ttf', '**/*.eot', '**/*.woff', '**/*.woff2'],
      filename: '[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
      limit: 7000,
      destDir: path.join(__dirname, 'build', paths.LOGIN_PUBLIC_URL, 'static/fonts'),
    }),
    image({
      include: ['**/*.svg'],
    }),
    styles({
       sourceMap: true,
       config: { path: paths.appPostcssConfig },
       mode: ['extract', 'login.css'],
       sass: {
         fibers: true,
       },
       inject: true,
    }),
    // postcss({ extract: true, config: false }),
    resolve({
      jsnext: true,
      extensions,
    }),
    clear({
      targets: ['build'],
    }),
  ],
};
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rollup Bundle</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="login.893de293.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Classic StackOverflow, not giving answers after 2+ years

Comment: Still no answer to this question? Does this plugin what you want to accomplish https://github.com/bengsfort/rollup-plugin-generate-html-template ?

Comment: I think mode `extract` will cancel `inject: true`.